# Swap Bytes in MIPS

Tags: mips

Lets say I have a hex value 0xfac3, and would like the result stored in my register to be 0xc3fa. How would I go about doing this? when I use rotate or shift I always have all of the 0's from the register in the middle of the two bytes. I need to get rid of those 0's. for example:

```
lw $t0, 0xfac3
ror $t0, $t0, 8
```

the resulting value I get is: **c30000fa**. I need to get rid of the 0's

Comment: MIPS doesn't have an ROR instruction: that is a pseudo instruction that is expanded by the assembler into multiple instructions.  If you use a simulator, and put that in, you'll be able to see those instructions.  You can write your own version of those instructions, to do what exactly you want.

Comment: Otherwise, can you think how to do it in C where we don't have any rotate operators (but there's shift, and, or operators).